# Replace dates older than 3 months via PowerQuery

Tags: excel, replace, powerquery

I am trying to remove dates from column `[Appt Date]` that are more than 3 months old and would like it to work on rolling 3 months so that I do not have to continuously go into the code and update the date. Below is the code I use to replace values that are pre-2023 which works perfectly.

```
= Table.ReplaceValue(#"Capitalized Each Word", each[Appt Date], each if Date.Year(Date.From([Appt Date])) < 2023 then null else [Appt Date], Replacer.ReplaceValue, {"Appt Date"})
```

I have done some searching online and tried to adapt some solutions to meet my requirements but had no success.

```
today=DateTime.LocalNow(),
yr = Date.Year(today),
mnth = Date.Month(today),
dy = Date.Day(today),
prev= #date(yr, mnth-3,dy),

= Table.ReplaceValue(#"Capitalized Each Word", each[Appt Date], each if Date.Year(Date.From([Appt Date])) < prev then null else [Appt Date], Replacer.ReplaceValue, {"Appt Date"})
```

This example doesn't return any expression errors or anything but dates older than 3 months are still showing in the `[Appt Date]` Column.

Any assitance/guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Remove the `Date.Year` function as you are currently comparing a year number to an actual date. (I'm slightly surprised you have any data left actually)

Comment: I feel so stupid that I completely overlooked that... Thank you very much for the swift response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the Date.Year function as you are currently comparing a year number to an actual date. (I'm slightly surprised you have any data left actually) –
Rory
Nov 30 at 9:36

Answer (score 0):

The following scenario can be covered in two steps. In 1st step, you need to find the difference based on the current date code shared below.
covered
Number.Round(Number.From((DateTime.LocalNow() - [DateStarted])/( 365.25 / 12 )) ,0 )

With the top code, you will get monthly information if the period is 3 or greater than 3 months you can use [Date] column as blank else remain the same values